# Linq Entity Framework - get all customers that Ids are not in many to many table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 tables:

Customer

Car

and many-to-many table MM, which stores:

Customer_Id     Car_Id

How do I get all Customers which Car_Id's are not in many to many table?

I tried like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomerModel>> GetNewCustomersForCar(int carId)
        {
            var sentCustomers = await _unit.Repository<Car>().Queryable()
                .SelectMany(a => a.AspNetUsers, (b, a) => new { b, a })
                .Where(b => b.Id == carId)
                .Select(ba => new CustomerModel()
                {
                    Id = ba.a.Id,
                    Email = ba.a.Email
                })
                .ToListAsync();

            var allCustomers = await _unit.Repository<AspNetUser>().Queryable()
                .Select(c => new CustomerModel()
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Email = c.Email
                }).ToListAsync();

            return allCustomers.Where(ac => !sentCustomers.Contains(ac));
```

So basically I select all customers for selected car, then I check all customers, and in the end I select from all customers that do not contain Id's from many to many customer table for selected customer.

Get all customers which didn't use car yet(all that used car are having id's for selected car in many to many table).

Answer (score 1):

if you have a `Cars`  navigation property in your `AspNetUser` entity, you could do this:

```
var query= await _unit.Repository<AspNetUser>()
                      .Queryable()
                      .Where(u=>!u.Cars.Any(c=>c.Id==carId))
                      .Select(c => new CustomerModel()
                                    {
                                        Id = c.Id,
                                        Email = c.Email
                                    })
                      .ToListAsync();
```

Also you can change your `Where`  to  `.Where(u=>u.Cars.All(c=>c.Id!=carId))`,could be more readable